# Meter resultado de checkbox y select en base de datos

Tags: html, sql, base-de-datos, checkbox, html-select

Tengo un formulario que al enviar los datos, estos se guardan en una base de datos. Los datos se envían correctamente con los campos de nombre y mensaje, pero también tengo campos de checkbox y de select, y no sé algunas cosas sobre eso:

1. ¿Tendría que ponerle la misma etiqueta de `<label for="checkbox">` y `<label for="select">`?
2. ¿Qué valor se tiene que poner en la base de datos para que reconozca el resultado tanto de las checkbox como del select?

Este es mi código:

```
        div class="form-group">
            <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" id="ejemplo" placeholder="Nombre Ejemplo" style="width: 30%">
          </div>
          <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
                <input type="checkbox"> 1
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
        <label>
                <input type="checkbox"> 4
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox"> 2
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
        <label>
                <input type="checkbox"> 5
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
                <input type="checkbox"> 3
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
        <label>
                <input type="checkbox"> 6
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
          <div class="col-md-offset-7 col-md-3"> 
          <select class="custom-select" style="width:100%;">
                <option value="0">Elige uno:</option>
        <option value="1">Uno</option>
        <option value="2">Dos</option>
        <option value="3">Tres</option> 
            </select><br>
          </div>

          <div>
      <br><label for="Mensaje">Mensaje</label>
          <textarea name="mensaje" class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Mensaje"></textarea><br>
          </div>
```

*EDIT*
Fichero que muestra los datos en la pantalla

```
<?php 

    //hacemos la conexion para la base de datos:
    $con= mysqli_connect('localhost','root','log159');

    //verificamos la conexion
    if(!$con){

        echo"No Se Encontro El Servidor";

    }else{

        $db= mysqli_select_db('prueba'); //nombre bbdd
    //verificamos la base de datos
        if(!$db){

            echo"No Se Encontro La Base De Datos";

        }
    }
    //Se Hace la sentencia sql:
    $sql="SELECT * FROM datos"; //nombre tabla

    //ejecutamos la sentencia de slq:
    $ejecutar=mysqli_query($sql);

    //traemos todos los valores en un array:
    $datos=mysqli_fetch_array($ejecutar);

    //imprimimos los datos de manera dinamica
    echo "<table border='1'>";
    echo"<tr>";
    echo "<th align='center'><b>Nombre</th>";
    echo "<th align='center'><b>Mensaje</th>";
    echo "<th align='center'><b>Check</th>";
    echo"</tr>";
    for($i=0; $i<$datos; $i++){
        echo"<tr><td>$datos[0]</td>";
        echo"<td>$datos[1]</td>";
        echo"<td>$datos[2]</td>";
        echo"</tr>";
        $datos=mysqli_fetch_array($ejecutar);
    }
    echo"</table>";
?>
```

En la última parte, hay 2 partes de `<echo>`, en la primera, que es la que imprime los datos, ¿habría que poner todos los checks? O solo con añadir la línea de "Check" como está ahí puesta serviría?
Y en la segunda parte de esos `<echo>`, ¿habría que añadir algo más?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Todos los `checkbox` necesitan un atributo `name` (como todos los `inputs` que se envian por formulario).
Ejemplo: `<input type="checkbox" name="check1">`

Los `checkbox` cuando no tienen al atributto `value`, llegan en `on` si estan checked o en `off` si no lo estan.

Ejemplo: `<input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="aceptado">`

En este último ejemplo se envia `aceptado` como valor para ese campo cuando está `checked`, en tu servidor si sus php lo capturas con un `$_POST['check1']`

Si este valor no estuviese `checked`, enviaría un valor `off`.

PD: lo de `on` y `off`, estoy solo un 75% seguro, lo digo pensando usando el lenguaje de PHP, no he visto como funciona en las nuevas versiones de PHP 7.*

EDITO:

En el caso del select, también necesita un atributo `name`, pero en este caso si no tiene seleccionado ninguna opcion envía `NULL`.

Ej:

```
<select name="select1">
  ... opciones
</select>
```

Comment: Tengo una duda sobre eso, tengo 2 ficheros php, uno que manda los datos y otro que los muestra en la tabla. Ya hice el que los manda, pero en el fichero que muestra los datos en la tabla me surgió una duda. Edité la pregunta añadiendo esta duda que tengo.

Answer (score 0):

No se puede añadir mucho más a lo dicho por Franklin'j Gil'z. Lo que tienes que tener muy claro es que se debe añadir un value, con el dato a enviar a nuestra BD, tanto en el chek como en los option de un select.